# how to change gmock verbosity level

Tags: c++, testing, googletest, googlemock, verbose

I want to change gmock warnings into errors in  all uninteresting gmock function calls.
I search some and I found that i should use --gmock_verbose=LEVEL flag but where should I add this flag?
Unfortunately I couldn't change all NiceMocks to StrictMocks.

Comment: this flag doesn't solve my issue, it just hide warnings. Is in Gmock any possibility to change warnings to errors without change NiceMock to StrictMock ?

Comment: That would be fundamental maintenance problem in your project if `NiceMock`  start generating errors because of that - it is 100% against their  design purposes. It is like requiring from good people to do bad things but - "please do not call them evil people"... Just use `StrictMock` - or create type-alias `ConfigurableMock` and once make it NiceMock, once StrictMock...

Answer (score 0):

> where should I add this flag?

You can add gmock flags like `--gmock_verbose=error` directly in the command line.

Otherwise, you can always specify verbosity on a per test basis by putting `::testing::FLAGS_gmock_verbose = "error";` in the test code itself.

Source: http://google.github.io/googletest/gmock_cook_book.html#controlling-how-much-information-gmock-prints